# How to aply multiprocessing on a for loop on items from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have a code that creates a graph based on the list `list_1`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()

list_1 = [[0,1,2,3], [3,6,2,1], [0,1,2,5], [2,5,4,9]]

added = []

for i in list_1:
    g.add_nodes_from (i)
    e1 = (i[0],i[1])
    e2 = (i[1],i[2])
    e3 = (i[2],i[3])                                                 
    added_now = []                      
    for edge in (e1,e2,e3):
        if not g.has_edge(*edge):
           g.add_edge(*edge)
           added_now.append(edge)

    added.append(i)

    for j in range(len(added)):
        if nx.shortest_path(g, i[0], i[3])!=i or nx.shortest_path(g, added[j][0], added[j][3])!=added[j]:
           for edge in added_now:
               g.remove_edge(*edge)
           added.remove(i)
           break

pos=nx.circular_layout(g)
plt.figure(3,figsize=(8,8))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos)
nx.draw(g,pos)   
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,pos)
plt.show()

print (added)
```

The algorithm selects the first element from `list_1`, adds nodes and edges, and then checks whether the shortest path condition is met in the resulting graph. For example, in the first step,this `nx.shortest_path (g, 0, 3) == [0,1,2,3]`. If so, then it goes to the next item from `list_1`. But if not, then it removes the newly added edges and goes to the next item from `list_1`. In this way a graph is created where in the list `added` are all matching elements from`list_1`, on which the algorithm `shortest_path` gives an unambiguous result.

```
added = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 4, 9]]
```

Because:

```
nx.shortest_path(g,0,3)==[0, 1, 2, 3] and 
nx.shortest_path(g,0,5)==[0, 1, 2, 5] and
nx.shortest_path(g,2,9)==[2, 5, 4, 9]
```

And graph:

[image]

If I assume that the order of selecting elements to check from `list_1` is not important and that the list is very large, then multiprocessing can be used here? If so, how?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that multiprocessing will improve performance in your case. There are no "heavy" long-running atomic computations that require no memory synchronisation, which is highly expensive without shared memory. Multiprocessing is fine for pure functional code or when you need to run several blocking operations in parallel with no concerns about performance. Since your algorithm is heavily imperative, multithreading is your only viable option, if you are not going to revise the algorithm. And since CPython's GIL doesn't not allow concurrent threads, you are left with Cython.

Comment: Even with lists containing a million items, multiprocessing will not be a good choice?

Comment: I was thinking about multiprocessing because I wanted to apply it to calculations in the computing cloud.

Comment: The thing is you update a global object multiple times for each value in `list_1`, which requires state synchronisation, i.e. serialising and deserialising a lot of objects while tossing them between the workers. Your algorithm is not particularly good for any sort of parallelisation (even multithreading, because you'd have to constantly lock and unlock the global  object), but it is absolutely unfit for multiprocessing. You should make it as stateless as possible and only run the stateless parts in parallel if you want to use multiprocessing.

Comment: I haven't analysed your algorithm thoroughly enough, but it seems like your outer iterations (`for in in list_1`) are independent from each other.

Comment: that's why I hoped it would be possible ;)

Comment: Consider function `f(G0, l) -> G`, where `G0` is an emtpy graph, `l` is a list from `list_1` and `G` is a graph produced by your procedure for `l`. Consider another function `с([G]) -> G`, where `[G] = [G1, G2, ..., Gn]` is a list of graphs produced by function `f` for each `l` in `list_1`. Can you guarantee that `c` is invariant under permutation of `list_1` (or likewise `[G1, G2, ..., Gn]`)?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that `c` combines individual graphs by adding all their nodes and edges into a single graph (the state of variable  `g` after the `for` cycle ends in your example)

Comment: Wydaje mi się, że tak, chociaż operacja funkcji `c` poprzez połączenie z bazy danych `[G]` jest ryzykowna i bez warunku wynik może nie być poprawny. Ale musiałbym sprawdzić gotowe rozwiązanie, wtedy byłbym pewien, czy to możliwe, czy nie. Ponieważ trudno sobie wyobrazić wszystko. Ale sam pomysł jest na razie interesujący :)

Comment: Я проанализировал ваш алгоритм. C теоретической точки зрения без дополнительных условий нельзя гарантировать, что вызов `nx.shortest_path(g, i[0], i[3])!=i` инвариантен относительно порядка итерации, потому что зависит от текущего множества ребер в графе. Соответственно, параллельное независимое исполнение скорее всего приведет к неверному результату, если оставить алгоритм без серьезных изменений.

Comment: I think I have to sleep with the problem, because for a week I have been trying to modify the algorithm itself, to give the same results, but for now without success ... thanks for showing interest :)

Comment: Seem's like your algorithm is naturally sequential (i.e. any type of parallel execution will invalidate the answer). Your problem might have a different solution. Can you formulate the problem itself?

Comment: this is a bit more of a problem in looking for a certain graph. post with a broader explanation (some other hints came in the comments), I posted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185129/157474 .
but unfortunately I am increasingly inclined to look for a completely different solution, because I am stuck to above all accelerate the current algorithm.

Comment: It seems code review users are as frustrated as I am with respect to understanding what you actually want to achieve. Please, invest your time into formulating the entire problem in mathematical terms without any code. It will help you and others find an optimal solution. Don't try to describe the way you want to solve it, rather describe the problem itself: the input, the expected output and the properties it should have.